# The definition of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

As history of thermodynamics say, it was a mystery that what is the required condition for a given energy conversion to take place? Like there are two possible events each conserving energy but only one is chosen. So, in order to resolve this Clausius introduced a quantity called [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) which was given by $\int dq/T$. But can I know the reason for which Clausius chose this integral or quantity, why not any other quantity (changes in whom, positive or negative, would decide the occurrence of a given event)? I hope there lies an explanation to this which does not use statistical mechanics.

Comment: Here's my own explanation: http://www.lightandmatter.com/html_books/0sn/ch05/ch05.html#Section5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use statistichal mechanics, you can view it as a completely mathematical thing. 
When you write the differential form $\delta Q$, you are not speaking of an *exact* differential, i.e. it is not really the differential of any function of the thermodynamical state.
Temperature is, in this case, called the *integrating factor*, which means that $\delta Q/T$ **is** an exact form, in particular, it's $dS$, the differential of Entropy. This is a way to let entropy come out.

On the other hand, much more physical explanations can be given.
The first uses obviously stat mech, but without making calculations, i can just tell you that $S$ turns out to be very closely connected with the number of possible microscopical states a thermodynamical (thus macroscopical) state can admit.

Finally, a reason is that the quantity $\int \delta Q/T$ is *never negative* in normal thermodynamical transformations, that is, it allows a simple formulation of the second principle.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Well, actually I was trying to seek an explanation without stats mech because I guess Clasius did not think of stats mech while providing a way to resolve the problem. By the way could you provide me few more physical explanations ?

Comment: Actually I absolutely don't know what historically speaking Clausius was thinking about, probably it  was the last reason I wrote. I don't have anything else in mind right now, but perhaps someone else more expert than me can help you.