# What is entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Can somebody please explain in detail what is entropy not a definition like its measure of disorderness. A complete  introduction from basics to what parameters it depends on as a thermodynamics point of view.

Comment: This seems like you need a chapter in a textbook, not an internet post. Can you narrow the scope of your question (a lot)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is entropy really?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131170/)